# can I pass an object to a class via template c++

Tags: c++, templates

Can I do this:

```
class A
{
    public:
    void print()
    {
         std::cout<<"A"<<std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
    public:
    void print()
    {
         std::cout<<"B"<<std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T>
class C 
{
     public:
     void say()
     {
          T.print();
     }
};

int main()
{
     A a;
     B b;
     C<a> c;
     c.say();
     C<b> d;
     d.say();

     return 0;
 }
```

If I don't want to use a base class for `A` and `B`, what is the best way (fast running speed) way of doing this?

Comment: You would have to use `T().print()` to create an instance. You could also just make `C::say` a template funciton, and not the whole class.

Comment: The entry point must return print and you forgot the semicolons behind the classes.
However you seem to mix up compile-time and run-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with your code.

You seem to be mixing up types with instances (or classes and objects).

This code should actually compile and work as intended.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
    void print()
    {
         std::cout<<"A"<<std::endl;
     }
};

class B
{
    public:
    void print()
    {
         std::cout<<"B"<<std::endl;
     }
};

template <class T>
class C 
{
     public:
     void say(T obj)
     {
          obj.print();
          // If T::print() were static, you could call it like that instead.
     }
};

int main()
{
     A a;
     B b;
     C<A> c; // template for C demands a class, not an object!
             // in practice this would mean you write 'A' instead of 'a' here
     c.say(a);
     C<B> d; // same here
     d.say(b);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Where `T` is a type `T.print();` is not valid C++.
Instead you have the following options:

***If you make `print` a static method you could do:***

```
void say()
{
     T::print();
}
```

This might be a good route if the `print` method does not need any state. It's nothing more that than a straight (possibly inlined) function call. So not much scope for performance problems.

***Otherwise you have to pass the object***:

```
void say(T object)
{
    object.print();
}
```

There are some options for how you would pass the object. Whether by value as above (assuming `T` isn't a reference/pointer type) or by reference. These may or may not have significance on the performance depending on the particular case.

***Or create an instance within the `say` method:***

```
void say()
{
    T().print();
}
```

For simple cases this is likely to optimise out to be essentially the same as the static `print` method case. Though of course the constructing a `T` could be potentially costly for less trivial cases.

Answer (score 0):

At first you forgot the semicolons behind the class declarations and somehow your main does not return an integer. So assuming thats fixed there is only a small amount of code there, which is still wrong, but is a huge impact. You mixed up **run**time and **compile**time.

```
 A a;
 B b;
 C<a> c;
 C<b> d;
```

You try to use a non-const instance as a template parameter, which makes no sense. It will be created on runtime, but on compiletime you have no clue about those. A template parameter does not take a non-const value, most of time it simply takes a *type*, like in your code. `template<class T>` or `template<typename T>` is expecting some type, not an instance of something. However you can recieve instances by doing things like `template<A myConstA>`.
Anyways you need to rewrite it, such that it recieves the *type*, as it is known at compile-time.

```
A a;
B b;

//you can do C<decltype(a)>, too
C<A> c;
C<B> d;
```

You have your print function like this:

```
void print()
{ T.print(); }
```

But you cannot call a non-static function without an instance! Thus you have a few possibilities to fix this. Either take a reference of type `T` and call from that, like so:

```
void print(T& t)
{ t.print(); }
```

or simply, if ok, do this:

```
void print()
{ T().print(); }
```

or make the `print` functions of both `A` and `B` static!
Try it [online](http://cpp.sh/5t6v)!

---

By the way whatever you do, if you decide not to make it static, make it a `const` function and `noexcept`, since it never throws and does change nothing from the instance.